# How to load data in Linq with 2 conditions

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to load data in Linq based on 2 conditions, but not able to get exact results:

```
dlo.AssociateWith<DBProp>(item => item.Tratable.Where(t => t.Flag == null && t.TratableChild.Flag == null ));
```

Here if all the tratablechild flags are Not NULL, I am getting first row value. I don't need it -
i.e in Linq Tratable is the parent class.

In this I have tratablechild as entityref, tratablechild contains some flag value for a single Tratable ID, but during runtime I just want to load tratablechild whose flag value is NULL.
Else I just want to set Tratablechild itself as NULL. How is this possible?

Comment: Argh... You need to better explain what you want.  Is `TratableChild.Flag` really a string?  Something doesn't smell right here.

Comment: Hi Robert, yes its a string

Comment: It can have NULL string or some value, i just need to load the data from TratableChild based on a condition i.e TratableChild.Flag == NULL.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean `string.IsNullOrEmpty(t.TratableChild.Flag)`?

Comment: No, i mistakenly wrote "NULL", it is a simple null. i want to load the row having null string for a perticular Tratable

Comment: Hi, i have added full code in this post. if you know please help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15654305/loading-entities-in-linq